# My button needs to update after an input field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I have the following problem, I made a form using HTML with some input fields.
I also made the submit button disabled using the following JS code:

```
  if(document.forms['form'].inputfield1.value == "")
    {
    document.forms[0].submit.disabled=true;
    }
    else {  
    document.forms[0].submit.disabled=false;
    }
```

This works fine, whenever I load the page the button is disabled, but when I fill in something it doesn't get enabled.

But whenever I place a value in my input field like so:

```
<input type="text" name="inputfield1" size="3" maxlength="3" value="12345">
```

And I load the page the button is enabled, proving the JS code works just fine.

I don't know if there is anyway to make the button refresh after someone used an input field  or anything like that.

I'm completely new to JS and PHP, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That check is made only on load and you seem to want to do this dynamically. It can be achieved through a `javascript event`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a javascript event to detect when the value changes and to run the validation. I would suggest [`onkeyup`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) for this as you will likely want it as the user is typing.

This can be done with javascript as follows...

Create an `onload` event to trigger when the page loads, this will register the events handlers for your input and call the initial check to set the default state:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByName("inputfield1")[0].onkeyup = validateForm;
    validateForm();
};
```

Then your function to do the validation:

```
function validateForm(){
    if(document.forms['form'].inputfield1.value == "")
    {
        document.forms[0].submit.disabled=true;
    }
    else {  
        document.forms[0].submit.disabled=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i did exactly what you told me to, but now my button is enabled by default whenever i load the page

Comment: Just call `validateForm()` in your main javascript scope, where you had the original code

Comment: Where exactly do I put it then? Just i my <script> where my function is too?

Srry, complete newbie in JS...

Comment: Btw it didnt work with the document.onload


but it did work when i just placed 'validateForm();' right above the function validateForm()

Answer (score 0):

You can use onkeyup function to do this simply

```
<input type="text" name="inputfield1" size="3" maxlength="3" value="12345" onkeyup='check()'>

function check() {
  if(document.forms['form'].inputfield1.value == ""){
    document.forms[0].submit.disabled=true;
}
else {  
    document.forms[0].submit.disabled=false;
}
}
```

Comment: my button is enabled when i load the page now =/